# Gmail business collaborative inbox

Tags: gmail, google-groups

I've just created a couple of Gmail business users and am now looking to set up a typical "sales@" email which all users should have access to. I'd really like this to work as a regular email address, that all users can access (perhaps another folder?) within their own Gmail login.

I've setup a collaborative group, making it available for the public to post to. I have verified that I am receiving the emails in my user inbox, however I'm not able to reply as "sales@".

Is this simply a checkbox I need to tick somewhere?

Is a collaborative group really even the correct way to do this? I see it creates a forum with all the messages listed - this isn't something I intend to use nor need.

Please let me know if there is a more suitable way.

Comment: Did you followed the instructions in the related help article [Use a group as a collaborative inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en)?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Google Group (e.g., sales@example.com) from your Google Apps and set it up as a Collaborative inbox. Instructions [from Google Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430).

To be able to reply as sales@ form your Inbox you need to use the Gmail's *Send Email As* feature. This feature allows you to send email as another user or group. [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).

The issue with Google collaborative inbox is that it does not work as a regular email account. Even if you forward the emails to your Gmail, if you reply from there, other users in your group will not see your reply unless you reply from the Collaborative inbox interface directly.

Have a look at [Hiver shared mailboxes](http://hiverhq.com). It helps users to manage shared mailboxes easily right from their Gmail. Your teammates can continue to stay and work from the Gmail without bothering about going to the Collaborative Inbox interface. You can choose to reply from your own email id or the group's email id too. And all replies and emails in a shared mailbox is visible to everyone in your team automatically.

Disclaimer: I'm associated with Hiver

Answer (score 0):

Gmail for Work by itself doesn't include such feature of "collaborative inbox".

Gmail for Work is part of Google Apps for Work which includes Google Groups for Business (GGB) among other apps. GGB could be used to create a group that will be used as a collaborative inbox. For details see [Using a group as collaborative inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en).

The collaborative inbox doesn't work as regular email account, as the group UI can't be used to choose which email address be included in the TO: field. It's best suited for cases when the email address will be used mostly to receive emails and reply to them.

It's worth to say that Gmail accounts are not intended to be shared between several users and doing so could make that Google block the account according to their policies to prevent abuse.